# Java finding a particular letter for the first time

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am developing a program in Java. I need to find a particular text inside a string. Suppose string is 'Hawaiie'. My need is to search for 'd' & 'e'. If 'e' comes first 'e' has to be returned and if 'd' comes first then 'd' has to be returned. In string 'Hawaiie' since 'e' is the first letter 'e' has to be returned. I tried the following code for that but it is returning only the position of letter, not the letter itself.

```
String str1 = new String("Hawaiee");
System.out.println(str1.indexOf('e');
```

Comment: Look at the String class. You'll find your answer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Why don't you create your own method taking the string as an arg and returning the letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    String str = new String("Hawaede");
    int a=str.indexOf('d');
    int b=str.indexOf('e');
    if(a!=-1 && a<b) 
    {
        return 'd'
    }
    else if(b!=-1) return 'e';
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this: here, if none of the characters are there: it will return 'o', you can put any default character for comparison.

```
  public char getFirstChar(String str) {

    int indexOfd = str.indexOf('d');
    int indexOfe = str.indexOf('e');
    if (str.indexOf('d') != -1) {
        if (str.indexOf('e') != -1) {
            if (indexOfd < indexOfe) {
                return 'd';
            } else {
                return 'e';
            }
        } else {
            return 'd';
        }

    } else {
        if (str.indexOf('e') != -1) {
                return 'e';
        } else {
            return 'o';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this will return 'o' for string "e".

Comment: in the first if statement: 
"e".indexOf('d') == -1
,so we go to the else branch and return 'o'

Comment: well, now it will return 'd', which is still wrong. How about you check your code before posting?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you need to get the index of each character (d & e) and compare the indexes. Then return the appropriate character depending on which index is less (don't forget to exclude -1 since that means it wasn't found).

Answer (score 3):

```
public char getFirstChar(String s, char a, char b){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);

        if (c == a){
            return a;
        }
        if (c == b){
            return b;
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public char myIndex(String str, char a, char b) {
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (a == c)return a;
        else if (b == c)return b;
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try splitting your string and then looping over it to locate your character.  Whichever one you find first gets returned

```
public class SO{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str1 = new String("Hawaiee");
    String[] sArray = str1.split(""); //Split to array
    String s = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++){
        s = sArray[i]; //Check each character
        if(s.equals("e") || s.equals("d")){ //If we get a match
            System.out.println(s + " appears first."); //Print
            break; //Break loop as we have the first character
        } else {
            if(i == sArray.length -1){ //If at the ned without a match
                System.out.println("No matches found");
            }
        } 
    }  
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> my need is to search for 'd' & 'e'. and if 'e' comes first 'e' has to
>   be return and if 'd' comes first then 'd' has to be return.

Try, to use `indexOf` to search letter present at word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getFirstChar("Hawaiee"));
}

public static char getFirstChar(String str) {

    int indexOfd = str.indexOf('d');
    int indexOfe = str.indexOf('e');

    if (indexOfd != -1 && indexOfe != -1) {

        return indexOfd < indexOfe ? 'd' : 'e';
    } else if (indexOfd != -1) {
        return 'd';
    } else if (indexOfe != -1) {
        return 'e';
    } else {
        return 'o';
    }

}
```

Comment: this will not determine which is first in the string

Comment: Ya... thanks Massud for your effort .. I need to get the first letter among e or d .. suppose in the string if 'e' comes first'e' has to be returned and if 'd' come first 'd' has to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the index in numeric value then by comparing you can decide either to pop "e" or "d" using char charAt(int index) function. Code wise it will look as following:

```
    String s="Hdiey";
int eIndex = s.indexOf("e");
int dIndex = s.indexOf("d");
System.out.println("eIndex "+eIndex+" dindex"+dIndex);
if(eIndex < dIndex)
    System.out.println(s.charAt(eIndex));
else
    System.out.println(s.charAt(dIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
    String str1 = new String("Hawaiee");

    if (str1.contains("e") && str1.contains("d") && str1.indexOf("e") < str1.indexOf("d")) {
        System.out.println("e");
    } else if (str1.contains("e") && str1.contains("d") && str1.indexOf("d") <str1.indexOf("e")) {
        System.out.println("d");
    } else if (str1.contains("e")) {
        System.out.println("e");
    } else if (str1.contains("d")) {
        System.out.println("d");
    } else {
        System.out.println("String does not contain 'e' or 'd' ");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

with pattern matching:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[ed]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Hawaiee");
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.printf("Start index: %d%n End index: %d%n Found character: %s%n", m.start(), m.end(), m.group());
}
```